# Parsing a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing

I am trying to parse a table from a switch.  If the state is "up" continue running through the 1000 iterations else halt the test.  Below is the table that I need to parse and is the output of the "crt.Screen.Send("show" + chr(13))" below in the code.

```
OS2(config-iap)# show 

IAP Summary Table

IAP         IAP     TX/RX Channel(s)                      Channel  WiFi            Cell      TX      RX                                                                
Name  State Type   Chains Primary + Bonds                 Setting  Mode   Antenna  Size     Power Threshold  Stations
----- ----- ------------- ------------------------------- ------- ------- -------- ------- ------ ---------  --------
iap1    up  .11abgnac 3x3   6                             auto     bgn    int-omni max      20dBm   -90dBm         0 
iap2    up  .11anac   3x3 153                             auto      anac  int-omni max      20dBm   -90dBm         0 
                                                                                                             ======== 
Totals:                                                                                                            0  

OS2(config-iap)#
```

Below is the entire Python code I am using to loop through a country-code toggle for 1000 iterations and check if the state of those IAP1/2 are in "up" or "down" state.  If "up" I'd like the program to continue through it's iterations else (if "down") to halt or stop the test.  The code below works without the for statement -  However, I have to visually see when the state switches to down state and halt the test manually.

```
import time

output=""

def Main():
    state="up"
    crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
    crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
    crt.Screen.Send("config" + chr(13))
    crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
    crt.Screen.Send("interface iap" + chr(13))
    crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
    virt = 0
    while virt < 1000: #1024 being the max number of VLANs
        virt += 1
        crt.Screen.Send("!" + str(virt) + chr(13))
        crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
        crt.Screen.Send("country-code us" + chr(13))
        crt.Screen.WaitForString("(config-iap)# ")
        time.sleep(3)
        crt.Screen.Send("show date-time" + chr(13))
        crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
        crt.Screen.Send("show" + chr(13))
        output = crt.Screen.recv(2000)
        output=state.decode('utf-8')
        ll=state.split(chr(13))
        for item in ll:
            if "iap" in ll:
                mm=item.split()
                if mm[1]==state:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
        #crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
        crt.Screen.Send("country-code-reset" + chr(13))
        crt.Screen.WaitForString("(config-iap)# ")
        crt.Screen.Send("show" + chr(13))
        crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
        time.sleep(5)
    crt.Screen.Send("exit" + chr(13))
    crt.Screen.WaitForString("# ")
        #time.sleep(1)
Main()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
AttributeError Error: 'SecureCRT.Screen' object has no attribute 'recv' File: /Users/Documents/SecureCRT_Scripts/country-code_1.py Line: 24 state = crt.Screen.recv(2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in your code,

```
if "iap" in ll:
```

should be,

```
if "iap" in item:
```

Comment: Awesome catch! Thank you.  Going further in the code now, but getting the following error now:

AttributeError

Error: 'SecureCRT.Screen' object has no attribute 'recv'
File: /Users/Documents/SecureCRT_Scripts/country-code_1.py
Line: 24

  state = crt.Screen.recv(2000)

Comment: not familiar with SecureCRT, but you may add some debug info in your script. It maybe some error you need handle before call recv.